# Pass Servlet Variable into JSP JSON page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I wish to use `$(member.email)`, a variable which I've passed into a JSP page, inside of a `<%` block on that same page. Its value shows up outside of the block, but inside the block it can't see it at all.

I have tried using `request.getAttribute("member.email")` but that merely  spit back a `null`. `Request.getAttribute("member.email")` gives me a string, which does not have the aforementioned value outside of the block.

I am unsure how to describe this problem any better than I have.

Comment: We need to see the servlet code where you add the value to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `${member.email}` basically works ["under the covers"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) (scope and null checks omitted):

```
Member member = (Member) request.getAttribute("member");
String email = member.getEmail();
out.print(email);
```

Please note that writing Java code in JSP files is considered a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). If you intend to serve JSON, you can better write it from inside the servlet instead of a JSP file. JSP is more for HTML.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you.

While I share your distaste, I'm afraid this one jsp file hasn't been complying too well with my servlet. I think I'll have to accept one bit of bad code over ten more hours of head aches.